# What is the goal of Variable using pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have this code :

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
d_real_data = Variable(d_sampler(d_input_size))
```

But I wonder what is the difference between `Variable(d_sampler(d_input_size))` and `d_sampler(d_input_size)`

I think it is two tensors but the values are different. So I was wondering what is the goal of this function Variable ?

Answer (score 7):

`Variable()` was a way to to use autograd with tensors. This is now deprecated and should not be used anymore. Tensors now work fine with autograd if the `requires_grad` flag is set to true.
From the  [official docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated)

> The Variable API has been deprecated: Variables are no longer
> necessary to use autograd with tensors. Autograd automatically
> supports Tensors with `requires_grad` set to `True`.